# Is a HNN extension of a virtually torsion-free group virtually torsion-free?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G=\langle X\ |\ R\rangle$ be a (finitely presented) virtually torsion-free group.  Let $H,K<G$ be isomorphic (finite index) subgroups of $G$ and let $\varphi:H\rightarrow K$ be an isomorphism.

Define the HNN extension $\Gamma$ of $G$ and $\varphi$ in the usual way, i.e. $\Gamma=\langle G,t\ |\ tht^{-1}=\varphi(h)\ \forall h\in H\rangle$.

Is $\Gamma$ virtually torsion-free?

<s>My thought is that if $T$ is a finite index torsion-free subgroup of $G$ and if $H$ and $K$ are finite index we should be able to look at the intersection of each of them with $T$.  So the group $\langle T,t\ |\ tht^{-1}=\varphi(h)\ \forall h\in T\cap H\rangle$ would be a finite index torsion-free subgroup of $\Gamma$.</s>

Also, can we say anything about the smallest index of a torsion-free subgroup?  For example if $G$ contains a torsion-free subgroup of index $k$, does $\Gamma$ contain a torsion-free subgroup of index $k$?  Or is the index bounded by some function of $k$?

Comment: You could try asking this question on mathoverflow

Comment: I've cross-posted it here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330632/is-a-hnn-extension-of-a-virtually-torsion-free-group-virtually-torsion-free

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, even assuming that $H,K$ have finite index in $G$: see https://mathoverflow.net/a/330658/14094, where I provided an example (where $G$ is finitely generated, virtually free, and $H,K$ are free subgroups of the same finite index). It relies on Burger-Mozes groups.

If one does not assume that $H,K$ have finite index, it's even simpler (see for instance https://mathoverflow.net/a/330655/14094).