# Is the free product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with $C_2$ virtually torsion-free?

Tags: group-theory

I  was thinking about the question
[Is a HNN extension of a virtually torsion-free group virtually torsion-free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192540/is-a-hnn-extension-of-a-virtually-torsion-free-group-virtually-torsion-free) and I started wondering whether or not $G = \mathbb{Z}\times C_2$ was a counterexample to the question. In the process, I came across the following question:

**Is $\mathbb{Z}* C_2=\left< t,x|x^2=1 \right>$ virtually torsion-free?**

A group is said to be virtually torsion-free if it has a finite index subgroup which does not contain elements of finite order.

I suspect that the answer is no because words of the form $t^nxt^{-n}$ all have order two within $\mathbb{Z}*C_2$. If $\mathbb{Z}*C_2$ has a finite index torsion-free subgroup $T$ then the cosets $t^nxt^{-n}T$ cannot all be distinct.

Comment: Yes. Indeed, every group with a single defining relation is virtually torsion free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the subgroup $N := \langle t,t^x \rangle$ is free and has index $2$ in $G$.